# while loop within foreach

Tags: php, arrays

I've got a form with questions which gets answered.  Then on the following page I'm trying to validate the questions to see if the answer is correct or not because eventually I must work out a percentage for the test.

```
$tid1 = $_SESSION['tid'];
$departmentid = $_SESSION['deptid'];
$userid = $_SESSION['userid'];

foreach($_POST['question'] as $key => $answer) {
    include 'datalogin.php';
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO ex_answer (id,class_name,testname,name,percentage,qnr,answer_chosen,points_scored,result)
VALUES ('0','$departmentid','$tid1','$userid','0','$key','$answer[0] $answer[1] $answer[2] $answer[3] $answer[4] $answer[5] $answer[6] $answer[7] $answer[8]','0','0')");

    $sql1="SELECT * FROM ex_question WHERE test_name = '$tid1' AND q_nr = '$key'";
    $result1=mysql_query($sql1);
    while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {
        $q_nr=$row1['q_nr'];
        echo $q_nr;
    }
}
```

The problem is (I think) that it is not selecting the question number `q_nr = '$key'` correctly from the table because `echo $q_nr` gives no output

Comment: does `include 'datalogin.php';` really need to be inside the `foreach` loop?  (I.e., does it really need to be included for every iteration, or can you just include it once, before the `foreach`?)  Also, please post your database table descriptions, this will help.

Comment: what happens if your `echo mysql_num_rows($result1);`? Do you get any rows? And what happens when your run the query with static values instead of variables (e.g. `SELECT * FROM ex_question WHERE test_name = 'testname' AND q_nr = '1'`)? Do you get the results you expect? If you do, make sure that `$key` and `$tid1` contain the values your expect them to. I can't see `$tid1` being defined anywhere - what happens in `datalogin.php`?

Comment: echo the line: $sql1="SELECT * FROM ex_question WHERE test_name = '$tid1' AND q_nr = '$key'";
Then you can see the problem.

Comment: @daiscog, I've moved include datalogin.php, thank you for that.

Comment: @DaveRandom, thanks already tried that it works if I replaced the variables with values

Comment: @mahadeb, I echoed the line and I get:  

SELECT * FROM ex_question WHERE test_name = '2' AND q_nr = '19'SELECT * FROM ex_question WHERE test_name = '2' AND q_nr = '29' which is correct, so why won't it work?  Any idea?

Comment: please check the output of $key and $answer are you getting these values?, and also add **or die (mysql_error())** to your insert query to get error messages from query point of view.

Comment: @punit I've already checked $key & $answer, I'm getting it

Comment: When you echo out the sql run it on your database client; what result do you get?

Comment: Then I get the correct result, It gives a SQL for each eg:  SELECT * FROM ex_question WHERE test_name = '2' AND q_nr = '19'SELECT * FROM ex_question WHERE test_name = '2' AND q_nr = '29' so if I run them 1 by 1 it works fine.

Comment: by the way what's the **primary key** of your table (if it's id) query insert 0 for each record inserted.

Comment: Hi, yes it is id, but the field is auto increment so it's inserting the next number

Comment: Thank you all, it's working now.  Eventually I dropped the table & recreated it and it worked, I think it was something to do with my table structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are getting a valid result (Test the sql in your Database client ) then you should just use the following to access it as an associative array:

```
mysql_fetch_assoc($result1);
```

instead of the mysql_fetch_array() or use
    mysql_fetch_array($result1, MYSQL_ASSOC)

Test what is being returned to you, comment out your while loop and then do:

```
$row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1);
print_r($row1);
```

before you while loop add the following for validation:

```
if (!$result1) {
    die('Could not query:' . mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: You should print out your result to see what you get, I have changed the above to show. is 'q_nr' a key returned in the print_r?

Comment: I changed it to: $sql1="SELECT * FROM ex_question WHERE test_name = '$tid1' AND q_nr = '$key'";
$result1=mysql_query($sql1);
$num_rows1 = mysql_fetch_row($result1);
//while($row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1)) {
//$q_nr=$row1['q_nr'];
//echo $q_nr;
//}
print_r(mysql_fetch_array($result1)); but still no ouput, but if I echo $sql1="SELECT * FROM ... then I see it's working, I'm lost

Comment: Check to see if mysql returns an error, again I have added the code above

Comment: You need `print_r($row1)`, not `print_r(mysql_fetch_array($result1))` -- the latter will get the NEXT row as a numerically-indexed array and print it; if your result only had one row, you'll get nothing!  And ` $num_rows1 = mysql_fetch_row($result1);` should probably be ` $num_rows1 = mysql_num_rows($result1);`.  You don't seem to understand the mysql_* functions.  Have your read [the PHP manual](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php)?

Answer (score 1):

Use `mysql_fetch_assoc` to be able to use column name indexes on returned array.

Answer (score 0):

You can also output the SQL and test it on the DB, that will show that you are getting the expected results